# How to set cwac-camera preview to use scaleType centerCrop?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, commonsware-cwac

Currently cwac-camera (https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-camera) zooms in on the preview of a picture, then when the picture is taken it is a different size.

What I'd prefer is for it to work like Snapchat, the image is cropped until it fills the entire screen, and the picture created does the same thing.

I can't see a way to configure the preview in such a lowlevel way unfortunately.

I overried getPreviewSize() and put a system.out in it and it appears to never be called also. Getting very confused.

```
  @Override
  public Camera.Size getPreviewSize(
      int displayOrientation, int width,
      int height,
      Camera.Parameters parameters) {

      Camera.Size size = CameraUtils.getOptimalPreviewSize(displayOrientation,
              width, height,
              parameters);

      System.out.println("getPreviewSize: " + size.width+"x"+size.height);

      return size;

  }
```

All I'm really aiming for is for the picture taken to be exactly the same as the preview.

In fact, I'm not even directly saving the picture the way cwac-camera is designed to (I'm going to allow the user to edit it and then upload it to the internet) so if there was a way to just grab the preview image in some way that would be good too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the getPreviewSize method was never being called due to a flag.

> If getRecordingHint() returns ANY or VIDEO_ONLY, though, CameraHost supplies the preview size via getPreferredPreviewSizeForVideo() instead of getPreviewSize(). If you wish to use a different preview size for video, return it, otherwise return null and we will use the results from getPreviewSize() instead.

So I overrid the getRecordingHint() to let cwac-camera know I'm only dealing with still images and therefore to actually implement my custom getPreviewSize method

```
  @Override
  public RecordingHint getRecordingHint() {
    return(RecordingHint.STILL_ONLY);
  }
```